# jUnit - advices

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I was browsing the stackoverflow to find out the common pieces of advice regarding using jUnit for tests, but still have a couple of questions. I understood that if it is complex method to be tested the best way to do it is split one to small separate parts and test each part. But the question is - why I should do it if all that small parts are easy to understand and I can test it "visually". I haven't had experince of developing complex applications which involves a number of methods which have to be covered by tests but I can't imagine why it is useful to test parts of big methods which provide obvious results.
The next question is regarding DAO-methods testing. Frankly I also don't understand how to test them. Could you take a look on the snippets below and give me an idea which the ways are to test the following methods? Thank you in advance.

1.What can be tested in such method?

```
public List<InvoicesBean> setPaymentStateInBean(List invoicesData, float sumBalance) {
    float dueState;
    float currentInvoiceAmount;
    float sumBalanceAfterIteration = sumBalance;
    String paymentState;

    Collections.sort(invoicesData, new BeanSortByDate());

    Iterator iterator = invoicesData.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        InvoicesBean invoicesBean = (InvoicesBean) iterator.next();
        dueState = getDueState(invoicesBean.getDueDate());
        currentInvoiceAmount = invoicesBean.getAmount();
        sumBalanceAfterIteration = sumBalanceAfterIteration - currentInvoiceAmount;
        paymentState = getPaymentState(dueState, sumBalanceAfterIteration);
        invoicesBean.setPaymentState(paymentState);
    }
    return invoicesData;
}
```

2.The method which makes request to DB and returns a List of selected data:

```
public List<InvoicesBean> getInvoicesData(String selectedContractor){
        float sumBalance = getPaymentTotalAmount(selectedContractor);
        List<InvoicesBean> invoicesDataWithPaymentsState;
        PaymentStateOperations paymentStateOperations = new PaymentStateOperations();

        try {
            preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT invoice_num, date, due_date, amount FROM invoices WHERE contractor_id IN" +
                    "(SELECT contractor_id FROM contractors WHERE contractor_name=?)");
            preparedStatement.setString(1, selectedContractor);
            resultSet = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
            invoicesData = new ArrayList<InvoicesBean>();
            while (resultSet.next()) {
                InvoicesBean invoicesBean = new InvoicesBean();
                invoicesBean.setNumber(resultSet.getString(1));
                invoicesBean.setDate(resultSet.getString(2));
                invoicesBean.setDueDate(resultSet.getString(3));
                invoicesBean.setAmount(resultSet.getFloat(4));
                invoicesData.add(invoicesBean);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {
                if (resultSet != null) {
                    resultSet.close();
                }
                if (preparedStatement != null) {
                    preparedStatement.close();
                }
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        invoicesDataWithPaymentsState = paymentStateOperations.setPaymentStateInBean(invoicesData, sumBalance);
        return invoicesDataWithPaymentsState;
    }
```

Comment: Your questions are reasonable, but I suggest asking one question in each Stack Overflow question, so each can have a specific title and answers. You could edit this one to include just your first question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to have tests to know that you haven't broken anything while developing.
When you're writing unit tests it's to make sure that your code is `robust`, that means that it fails gracefully or handles bad input in a correct way.

Trivial functions might not need to be tested always, but where do you draw a line between a non-trivial and a trivial method? That is different for every developer, what you should take care `not to test` is the language itself, which I would say something like this is akin to (the example is stupid but just to prove a point):

```
public String areBothTrue(bool a, bool b) {
    return a && b;
}
```

However suppose you have a very simple method that just adds two integers, what could be worth testing?

```
public int sum(int a, int b) {
   return a+b;
}
```

Well this method will always have an predictable outcome, but what about the `input`? Suppose the input is `Integer.MAX_NUM` and `5`, what is the result (Hint it wont be the sum of the two values)?
In this case what is important is what is the `context` for this method, if its purpose is just to sum two integers the way that Java does then it is perfectly fine, but if it is supposed to add a value, lets say in my bank account, then if I'm very rich I will very soon be a very poor man. :(

What I want to say is that you shouldn't think of unit testing as testing that your function does what it does, what you should test is that it does, what it does `correctly` even when the input is bad.

I won't go over your snippets so much because I don't know what is required of them, but if you look at `getInvoicesData` you can see that it will return null if there is an SQLException. This means that the thing that you think is a list is actually null because there you couldn't connect to the database which means that you must check for that.

**TL;DR**

Test that your method does, what it does `correctly`.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear "right" and "wrong" when writing tests, although you'll find tons of books and articles, but here is some (personal) advice to guide you, specifically about using JUnit:

- A unit tests tests one single unit of your code. Depending on your code, this is not necessarily a single class, but it is a logical piece of code, which often is combined in one class. So when testing that, you have to be either able to provide all external references used in the tested code or mock them out (e.g. by using frameworks such as [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/)).
- It is a good practice to implement the code and the test code together. I personally don't like the idea of test-first, since this is not practical for many cases (I like the cite "Test-first works well for Fibonacci"). But when writing a test at about the same time than the code, it helps you to design the code so that it's  better testable.
- Don't test everything (e.g. getters, setters), test reasonable. A common suggestion is testing everything with a [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity) higher than 2. That means, if you have a piece of code with ifs or loops, each possible path makes it more complex and your test has to scope with it and go (ideally) through all paths. Often this is not practical, forcing you to select reasonable ones (and documenting why).
- If you have a test which need several components, then it's more than a unit test. But often the line is hard to draw. For example, if you need a database connection, then it's certainly more than a unit test - still you can write a JUnit test for it, if testing an entity. If you need a container for components (e.g. an app server), then frameworks like [Arquillian](http://arquillian.org/) help you with that.